# Access - Select distinct records where only one column is distinct

Tags: select, ms-access-2007, unique

I have an Access table with two columns (ID and Active) with data like the following:

```
ID  |  Active
------------
123 | 0
124 | 0
125 | 0
123 | 1
314 | 1
948 | 1
```

I want to select the distinct records that have a unique ID (that only exist once, not just the first time they exist), but I also need the Active value.  If I do a

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID from table1
```

I get the unique IDs, but not the sheet.  It also returns `123` which isn't unique in the table.   If I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from table1
```

I get duplicate IDs if they have different Active values.  I need a query to get the unique IDs and their associated Sheet value.  It would return the following:

```
ID  |  Active
------------
124 | 0
125 | 0
314 | 1
948 | 1
```

Do I need to put these into two different tables and do an outer join?  Active is only ever 0 or 1.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM table1 GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(Id)=1)
```

Comment: That will leave 123 out altogether, whereas select distinct would include it.

Comment: @David: I don't understand. You said you wanted "to select the distinct records that have a unique ID"; that's what my proposed answer does, returning rows with ids 124, 125, 314 and 948, as you request in your sample return data. It doesn't return rows with id 123 because that id appears twice, i.e. it's not unique. Am I getting you right?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else, if you want at least one record returned for each ID, omitting any duplicates thereafter. A query similar to CesarGon's subquery will work, provided you want the first or last result for Active:

```
SELECT ID, First(table1.Active) as Active FROM table1 GROUP BY ID;
```

That will get you want you want:

```
ID  |  Active
------------
123 | 0
124 | 0
125 | 0
314 | 1
948 | 1
```

If you want the last value for Active:

```
SELECT ID, Last(table1.Active) as Active FROM table1 GROUP BY ID;
```

That will get you:

```
ID  |  Active
------------
123 | 1
124 | 0
125 | 0
314 | 1
948 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Max(ACTIVE) from table1

To give

### ID  |  Active

124 | 0
125 | 0
123 | 1
314 | 1
948 | 1